# Why does Jackson string do not show int values?

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to understand Jackson and have to ask you one thing about it.

In the example below I have two classes. One of them - object to be converted to JSON, another - main method.
I know that Jackson needs default constructor but decided to experiment. I have two constructors.
So the question is - why is my output `{"name":"Lion"}` and int value can not be seen at all?

```java
public class Lion extends AbstractCat {
    int age;
    public String name;
            
    public Lion(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
            
    public Lion() {};
            
}
```

```java
public class Var {
            
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {
            
        Lion lion = new Lion(32,"Lion");
        System.out.println(converToJSON(lion));
    }
        
    public static String converToJSON(Object o) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(stringWriter,o);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `age` is not `public`?

Comment: can you add a getter for your private variable `age`?

Comment: public int age will solve your problem.

Comment: @ErwinEngel you should add public keyword or add getter method for age attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson ignores `age`, because it is private. Either you make `age` public or add a public getter method (i.e. `public int getAge() { return age; }`). The latter is usually the prefered variant as public fields are exposing your classes internals.